# How to get mathbf to work properly in unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

**EXAMPLE I**

In short, I'm trying to reproduce the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[bold-style=ISO]{xits-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\[
PV=nRT\left(1+\mathbf{\frac{B(T)}{\left(V/n\right)}}+\frac{C(T)}{\left(V/n\right)^2}+\dots\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

The above code does exactly what I want, except not for an arbitrary font.

---

**EXAMPLE II**

In the `unicode-math` manual, I find a couple of commands to construct my own math font, but for any font that isn't `XITS`, I can't get it to work. Consider for instance the following code instead:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/YzseRs5.png?1]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{bm}
\setmathfont{Georgia}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{Georgia Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbf]{Georgia Bold}%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
All of these produce a different result, none of which are desirable:
\[
B(T)=\bm{B(T)}=\mathbf{B(T)}
\]
\end{document}
```

As you can see, each command results in something different (the first and second look alike barring the brackets, which are slightly different), and everything seems to be in bold shape. This happens even when I exclude the line with the per cent signs `%%%%%%`, or if I try to use e.g.

```
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin}]{Georgia Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbf/{latin,Latin}]{Georgia Bold}
```

---

**EXAMPLE III**

If I delete the lines using the `[range=\mathbf]` and `[range=\mathit]` keys, I suddenly get the desired result:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/gHOSbwM.png?1]

Fantastic!

---

So how can I construct my math font if the fonts are not well-organized* (in which case I'd have to declare each shape manually)? More specifically, if I'd want to obtain the last result (as outlined in example III), how could I do so using the `[range=\math*]` keys to declare the entire math alphabet step by step?

* = What I mean with this is that the font does not have its shapes all in one folder, but instead has each shape manually defined. This is quite often the case for fonts with several different weights, that do not obey the scheme of names that we often refer to as "SemiBold", "Bold", "BoldExtended" and so forth.

Comment: What are you really using for the main maths font? As written, your MWE is clearly going to generate a bunch of complaints just because Georgia is not a maths font. (`\setmathfont...` won't work.)

Comment: @cfr I had some success defining random fonts as roman/italic math fonts from e.g. Times, Lexicon, etc. No complaints in the console. It's really just `\mathbf` which poses problems.

Comment: Well, if I compile your example, I get a lot of warnings - not just about bold. This is expected because Georgia is not a maths font and so the attempt to use it is mostly going to fail. This is not to say that you won't get some bits set in Georgia but you will certainly get a lot of warnings about all the other bits. An example of just one of the many warnings I get is `* OpenType feature 'Style=MathScript' (+ssty) not available for font 'Georgia'
* with script 'Math' and language 'Default'.` Nothing whatsoever to do with bold.

Comment: Try typesetting `\sum_{i=1,\dots,n}^{\infty} x^{\sqrt[i]{\frac{1}{i}}}` after setting Georgia as the maths font.